# Iterate through an array of object that is provided by an observable and call http request foreach object.id?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

With routing in Angular in the component `ngOnInit` method I get a genre id by observable, within that observable I call a method with a service which makes an HTTP request.

```
  this.movies: Movie[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      let id = +param.get('id');

      this.movieService.getMoviesByGenres(id).subscribe( response => {
        this.movies = response['results'];
      });
    });
  }
```

it returns this:

```
   "results": [
    {
      "vote_count": 664,
      "id": 287947,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.4,
      "title": "Shazam!",
      .
      .
      .
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 3623,
      "id": 299537,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.2,
      "title": "Captain Marvel",
      .
      .
      .
    }, ...
   ]
```

What it returns are movies without casts, so I need to request the casts for the movie by calling another HTTP request for each movie that the first request returns and push the second request information of casts to the `movies[i].cast` array.

So basically what I would like, looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      let id = +param.get('id');

      this.movieService.getMoviesByGenres(id).subscribe( response => {
        this.movies = response['results'];
      });

      //pesudo code
      foreach(this.movies as movie) {
             this.movies[current element].casts = 
                  this.movieService.getCastByMovieId(movie.id);
      }
    }); 
  }
```

getting the movies by genre and when the result arrives, iterating through the `movies[]` array and call the method to get the cast by the movie id and add the casts to the movie `casts: string []` property. And return `this.movies: Movies[]` which now contains the casts as well.

Comment: Why are you handling it on the client side? Can you handle it on server-side only? This iteration will make multiple HTTP requests, and which is not necessary.  I request you to handle it on the server side only and return the complete movies array with CasId id on the server, and save the n number of calls.

Comment: It would make so much sense but unfortunetly i cant handle it on the server side, because the server does not belong to me.

Comment: Ok, I have understood your problem statement. Where are you lacking now? Are you getting any error? because your pseudo code looks good.

Comment: foreach-ing the this.movies array gives error as it is undefined, because the http request has not fineshed yet that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are working in Angular, you can also harness the power of RxJS for this, with something like this

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
    let id = +param.get('id');

    this.movieService.getMoviesByGenres(id).pipe(
      map(response => response['results']),
      mergeMap((movies: any[]) => {
        return forkJoin(
          movies.map(movie => {
            return this.movieService.getCastByMovieId(movie.id)
              .pipe(
                map((res: any) => {
                  movie.cast = res;
                  return movie;
                })
              );
          })
        )
      }))
      .subscribe(movies => {
        // Your logic here
      });
  })
}
```

Basically you get the movies first, then pipe the result through a forkJoin, which executes the requests all together keeping the order, add the result to movie.cast and returning the complete array at the end. In this way you also know when execution is complete.

Remember that if a request inside forkJoin fails, the entire execution fails, so you should handle the error specifically for each request.

Comment: Thank you, it works and i am happy it is solved with RxJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const self= this; 
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      let id = +param.get('id');

      self.movieService.getMoviesByGenres(id).subscribe( response => {
        self.movies = response['results'];
        for(let movie of self.movies){
            self.movieService.getCastByMovieId(movie.id).subscribe((result)=>{
               self.movies[current element].casts = result;
           });
        }
      });
    }); 
  }
```

I'm using self as a variable because the context of inner service different than the component. In short, The only for 'this' is different for service and component.

Note: In your movieService, make you return the HTTP request, else it will not return Observable and hence the component will not be able to subscribe it.

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the array by making end-point request like

**In Ts file**

```
  let listToUpdate = [{...}, {...},...];

this.serviceObj.postData(listToUpdate).subscribe(
    response => console.log(response),
    error => console.error(error),
    () => console.info("All requests done") 
);
```

**In Service file:**

```
import { from } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";

   ...

postData(listToUpdate){

  return  from(listToUpdate).pipe(
  concatMap(payload => this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/billing/balance-statement', payload))
  );
}
```